# ClearTimeout usage best practice within a promise

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have a question about clearTimeout method (sorry in advance for noob question). I am wondering where is the best place to clearTimeout in this following code? I have a "getResponse()"function which will be called multiple times. I am not sure where would be the best place to put the clearTimeout so that it will clear the timeout as soon as responseTimeout either resolves or rejects.Thanks

```
function getResponse() {
    const responseTimeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let id = setTimeout(() => {
            if (!messageHandled) {                       
                reject(`Timed out to get response`);               
            }                      
        }, 3000);
    });

    const responsePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // some code which returns response promise
    });

    return Promise.race([
        responsePromise,
        responseTimeout
    ]);
}
```

Comment: In the given code, you are not calling `clearTimeout`, did you forget to add it? But anyway, you actually don't need to clear it at all. Your promise.race will be resolved only once, by the first promise to resolve, and will ignore the other one. So what you currently have should be just fine.

Comment: I didn't forget it, I wasn't sure where to put it. In the Promise.race when the first one takes longer and timeoutpromise rejects, should I clear the timeout?The getResponse function will be called mutiple times and that 's why I want to clear it. Let me know if my thoughts are not correct

Comment: updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: Ah I thought this code block was the *first draft*  you talked about. Personally, I wouldn't clear it, it doesn't hurt to have a simple promise rejection being silently ignored, while keeping complicated closures just in order to be able to cancel this really small timedout execution will produce more complicated to maintain code. But that is opinions. + I don't know what happens to forever-pending Promises in term of GC. It might actually be better to not clear the timeout at all. But if you really want to do it, then initialise `id` inside `getResponse`, and clear it in `responsePromise`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I'll do it in the promise itself and avoid the overhead of two separate promises.

```
function getResponse(...params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error("Timed out to get response"))

      // some code to abort request
    }, 3000)

    // some code which resolves promise
  })
}
```

Usefully, promises ignore later resolutions and/or rejections after you resolve it the first time. If you can programmatically abort it without firing the resolution logic, this becomes much easier to do, but even if you can't, you can always slap a boolean to block future requests along the way. It also makes it easier to add support for canceling later on, which is also helpful. If you need to also shut down the timeout (in case you're doing some DOM mutation or file reading - you rarely need to do this), you could do something like this:

```
function getResponse(...params) {
  return new Promise((reallyResolve, reallyReject) => {
    let resolved = false
    let id = setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error("Timed out to get response"))
      abort()
    }, 3000)

    // I'll use these instead of the `resolve`/`reject` callbacks directly.
    function resolve(value) {
      if (resolved) return
      resolved = true
      clearTimeout(id)
      reallyResolve(value)
    }

    function reject(value) {
      if (resolved) return
      resolved = true
      clearTimeout(id)
      reallyReject(value)
    }

    function abort() {
      // some code to abort request
    }

    // some code which resolves promise
  })
}
```

This makes it so I don't have to worry about orchestrating everything, but it still works.

If you don't need abort logic (you only really need it for network requests and similar), this becomes a lot simpler:

```
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise((_, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("Timed out")), ms)
  })
}

function getResponse(...params) {
  return Promise.race([
    timeout(3000),
    doSomethingAsync(),
  ])
}
```

Comment: @Kaiido Fixed. Thanks for the catch. (I so rarely use `Promise.race` I almost forget about it at times.)